# Do we need to prove that replacing any of the variables of a tautology by a compound proposition or true/false gives a tautology?

Tags: proof-writing, propositional-calculus

For example we know that $\left(\left(p\rightarrow q\right) \wedge\left(q\rightarrow r\right)\right)\rightarrow\left(p\rightarrow r\right)$ is a tautology and we can prove it, but do we need to prove that for example $\left(\left(p\rightarrow \left(q\vee r\right)\right) \wedge\left(\left(q\vee r\right)\rightarrow r\right)\right)\rightarrow\left(p\rightarrow r\right)$ or $\left(\left(\left(p\wedge s\right)\rightarrow False\right) \wedge\left(False\rightarrow r\right)\right)\rightarrow\left(\left(p\wedge s\right)\rightarrow r\right)$ (they are achieved by replacing propositional variables of the first tautology) are tautologies too? and if so how to do it?

Comment: Using the "general" def of *tautology* where we can use schematic letters (meta-variables standing for formulas: $\varphi, \psi, \ldots$) instead of sentential letters ($p, q, \ldots$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is so "obvious", that it is not usually proved.

See Alonzo Church, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=KJbKCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA97) (1956), page 97.

We need a Lemma, proved by induction on the compelxity of the formula $A$:

> $A$ and $B$ being formulas and let $A[B/p]$ the formula resulting from $A$ replacing each occurrence of the sentential letter $p$ with $B$.
>
> If $p_1, \ldots, p_n, p$ are distinct variables among which are all the variables occurring in $A$ and all those occurring in $B$ and if for an assignment $v$ such that $v(p_i)=a_i$ and $v(p)=b$ we have that the value of $B$ is $b$ (i.e. $v(B)=b$) and the value of $A[B/p]$ is $c$, then the value of $A$ for the said assignment $v$ is also $c$.

From this Leamma, we have that: if for an assignment $v: v(A[B/p])=$ **F**, then also $v(A)=$ **F**.

*Conclusion*: if $A$ is a *tautology*, also $A[B/p]$ must be a *tautology*.